# multiple issuers detected for the same token

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SP2016 Server and I am trying to setup app environment. I added the certificate as SPTrustetSecurityTokenIssuer and SPTrustetdRootAuthority but when I open the app there is a 401 error. ULS says; "multiple issuers detected for the same token".
Also i restartet the Security Token Service application pool and the server multiple times.

[uls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyW87.png)